# Programmatically flip UIPageController page from unconventional UIPageController setup

Tags: ios, swift, uipageviewcontroller

Similar questions to mine have been asked numerous times, however, in my situation I set up the `UIPageViewController` in an unconventional method. And over the past day and a half of trying to implement the other questions solutions into my program, I have come to believe that they only work with a more conventional method of setting up the `UIPageViewController`. For some background, I have two `UIViewControllers` that are being transitioned between in a `UIPageViewController`. I would like to be able to programmatically change the page of the `UIPageViewController` from one of the views controllers.
Here is my `UIPageViewController` class:

```
class transitionController: UIPageViewController, UIPageViewControllerDataSource, UIPageViewControllerDelegate {

lazy var arrayVC: [UIViewController] = {
    return [
        self.VCInstance(name: "VC1"),
        self.VCInstance(name: "VC2")
    ]
}()

private func VCInstance(name: String) -> UIViewController {
    return UIStoryboard(name:  "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: name)
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.dataSource = self
    self.delegate = self
    if let VC1 = arrayVC.first{
        setViewControllers([VC1], direction: .forward, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
public func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerBefore viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {
    guard let viewControllerIndex = arrayVC.index(of: viewController) else{
        return nil
    }
    guard FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser?.uid != nil else {
        return nil
    }
    let previousIndex = viewControllerIndex - 1
    guard previousIndex >= 0 else {
        return nil
    }
    guard arrayVC.count > previousIndex else{
        return nil
    }
    return arrayVC[previousIndex]
}


public func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerAfter viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {
    guard let viewControllerIndex = arrayVC.index(of: viewController) else{
        return nil
    }
    guard FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser?.uid != nil else {
        return nil
    }
    let nextIndex = viewControllerIndex + 1
    guard nextIndex < arrayVC.count else {
        return nil
    }
    guard arrayVC.count > nextIndex else{
        return nil
    }
    return arrayVC[nextIndex]
}
}
```

I have tried to flip the pages with this block of code in my VC1:

```
let vc = UIStoryboard(name:  "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "VC2")
transitionController().setViewControllers([vc]?, direction: .Forward, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

I believe that this doesn't work as I am creating a new instance of the transition controller(I could be wrong).

How can I programmatically flip pages of the `UIPageViewController` from within the VC1 or VC2 classes using my method of setting up the `UIPageViewController`?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Pass a weak reference of the `PageViewController` to each view controller, then when you need to transition, each view controller just calls back to the parent page view controller.

Comment: @sbarow how do I do that? Is it an outlet?

Comment: @sbarow can you make answer with some more detail?

Comment: In your `VCInstance` method, pass in a reference of `self` i.e `transitionController` to each created viewController. In the viewController save the passed in instance to a variable you a weak reference you create.